# Dual 6-core vs 4 core for multi-threaded C++

Tags: multithreading

Why would dual socket 6-core cpus be slower than a 4 core cpu when running multithreaded C++ applications? Tested a C++ app in a dev environment with a 4core cpu and it was faster than on a dual socket 6-core server. Both environments are Ubuntu. The only reason I can come up with is that the communication between the two 6-core sockets is slowing it down since inter-core communication is faster but on the other hand, I had the impression that the multi-threaded application would benefit from the dual socket scheme.

Comment: Could be any number of things. Primary suspect is that that code isn't very scalable and you're just paying more for synchronization with more threads/cores.

Comment: Thanks, that seems very likely. So inter-socket communication has nothing to do with it?

Comment: Probably has some impact. It is necessarily more expensive to  e.g. invalidate cache lines on two physically distinct chips than on a single one (assuming all else equal, which never happens). Could be memory bandwidth, NUMA issues, different generations of instruction sets, ...